# change background img each time by clicking link

Tags: javascript, image, background, hyperlink

```
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var backImage = new Array();
backImage[0] = "pics/img02.jpg";
backImage[1] = "pics/img03.jpg";
backImage[2] = "pics/img04.jpg";
backImage[3] = "pics/img05.jpg";

function changeBGImage(whichImage){
if (document.body){
document.body.background = backImage[whichImage];
backImage = backImage++;
}
}

//-->
</script>
<a href="javascript:changeBGImage(2)">Change</a>
</body>
```

sorry, i don't get how i exactly should properly integrate code here -hopefully it still worked. what i want to do here: change the background (that works) than add plus one to the background counter so that the next time the link is clicked the next background shows (that doesn't work). it should be quite simple but i couldn't figure it out nevertheless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static counter that counts from 0 to 3.

```
var cnt = 0;

function changeBGImage(){
  if (document.body){
    document.body.background = backImage[cnt];
    cnt = (cnt+1) % 4; // mod 4
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues in your code

`backImage = backImage++;`

Doesn't increment `backImage` as you expect. The syntax should be simply `backImage++;`

Also, to set the background image you need `document.body.style.background` or `document.body.style.backgroundImage = url(...)`

*Edit*

Over and above cycling through the backgrounds via the click handler, if you also need to set the initial background, try something like below, with the initial background set in `window.onload`.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VAY4K/15/)

```
var backImage = [];
var whichImage = 0;

backImage[0] = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/000000.png";
backImage[1] = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/FF0000/000000.png";
backImage[2] = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/00FF00/000000.png";
backImage[3] = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/0000FF/000000.png";

function changeBGImage(reseedWhichImage){
    // If caller has specified an exact index, then reseed to this
    if (reseedWhichImage != undefined)
    {
        whichImage = reseedWhichImage;
    }
    if (document.body){
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + backImage[whichImage] + ")";
        whichImage++;
        if (whichImage >= 4){
            whichImage = 0;
        }
    }
}

// During global load, set the initial background
window.onload = changeBGImage(2);
​
```

Comment: this solution appears more elegant -still i am unable to get an initial background, how come?

Comment: The initial background is set by the global `var whichImage = 2;`

Comment: @user1831854 I've updated the answer showing how you can set the initial background, and updated the fiddle as well.